# BPEL designer for IntelliJ Idea

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, designer, bpel

Is there a BPEL designer for IntelliJ Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist yet. You are welcome to request it in [YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: What's happening with the BPEL designer? I know that it is not in your current/future plans but I wish a tool will be available someday soon...